# Google Workspace SSO with Itop

Tags: google-sso

I was trying to figure out how I can integrate Google SSO to **Itop**. I have seen options for integrating with LDAP.

Comment: Please give your current iTop version.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible out of the box.

That being said, since iTop v2.7 it provides an authentication API which allows you to add Google as one of the authentication provider using OAuth. You won't be able to have SSO but you will be able to connect to iTop using your Google account.

Check [here](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=2_7_0%3Arelease%3A2_7_whats_new#api_authentication) for details about the authentication API, then check [here](https://www.itophub.io/wiki/page?id=2_7_0%3Acustomization%3Astart#by_writing_your_own_extension) for how to make an iTop extension.